# Limited functionality in the ESA SNAP toolbox on Mac OS M1 Silicon Chip

Tags: sentinel-snap, macos

I am working on Mac OS (on the Silicon processor) using the latest version of the SNAP toolbox. Even though I installed the Azul JDK 8.0, I was not able to make the SNAP toolbox work. This bug has been repeatedly reported on various platforms. The GUI is not functional.

Based on certain suggestions which I found over the internet, I took the following steps:

1. Removed the `snap` folder from `/Applications/snap/`
2. Restarted the
   `snap` application using the Launchpad.
3. The system complained about
   not finding the plugins, and asks for disabling them.
4. I found a
   button saying `Disable plugins and continue`. I continued.  This
   enables the working of the SNAP toolbox.
5. I uninstalled and
   reinstalled all the plugins which are available on SNAP.
6. However, I
   see that the menus are not completely available. For example,
   `Linear from/to dB` is not available.
7. Likewise, some of the menus
   are not complete, which are indeed available on the Linux platform.

What can I do to make these menu items available?